# Word Net - Word Synonyms & related word constructs - Java or Python

Tags: java, python, nlp, text-mining, wordnet

I am looking to use WordNet to look for a collection of like terms from a base set of terms.

For example, the word ***'discouraged'*** - potential synonyms could be: `daunted, glum, deterred, pessimistic`.

I also wanted to identify potential bi-grams such as; `beat down, put off, caved in` etc.

How do I go about extracting this information using Java or Python? Are there any hosted WordNet databases/web interfaces which would allow such querying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easiest to understand the WordNet data by looking 
at the Prolog files. They are documented here:

http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/prologdb.5WN.html

WordNet terms are group into synsets. A synset is a maximal 
synonym set. Synsets have a primary key so that they can be used 
in semantic relationships.

So answering your first question, you can list the different 
senses and corresponding synonyms of a word as follows:

```
Input X: Term
Output Y: Sense  
Output L: Synonyms in this Sense  

s_helper(X,Y) :- s(X,_,Y,_,_,_).  
?- setof(H,(s_helper(Y,X),s_helper(Y,H)),L).
```

Example:

```
?- setof(H,(s_helper(Y,'discouraged'),s_helper(Y,H),L).  
Y = 301664880,  
L = [demoralised, demoralized, discouraged, disheartened] ;  
Y = 301992418,  
L = [discouraged] ;  
No
```

For the second part of your question, WordNet terms are 
sequences of words. So you can search this WordNet terms 
for words as follows:

```
Input X: Word  
Output Y: Term

s_helper(X) :- s(_,_,X,_,_,_).  
word_in_term(X,Y) :- atom_concat(X,' ',H), sub_atom(Y,0,_,_,H).
word_in_term(X,Y) :- atom_concat(' ',X,H), atom_concat(H,' ',J), sub_atom(Y,_,_,_,J).
word_in_term(X,Y) :- atom_concat(' ',X,H), sub_atom(Y,_,_,0,H).
?- s_helper(Y), word_in_term(X,Y).
```

Example:

```
?- s_helper(X), word_in_term('beat',X).  
X = 'beat generation' ;  
X = 'beat in' ;  
X = 'beat about' ;  
X = 'beat around the bush' ;  
X = 'beat out' ;  
X = 'beat up' ;  
X = 'beat up' ;  
X = 'beat back' ;  
X = 'beat out' ;  
X = 'beat down' ;  
X = 'beat a retreat' ;  
X = 'beat down' ;  
X = 'beat down' ;  
No
```

This would give you potential n-grams, but no so much
morphological variation. WordNet does also exhibit some
lexical relations, which could be useful.

But both Prolog queries I have given are not very efficient.
The problem is the lack of some word indexing. A Java
implementation could of course implement something better.
Just imagine something along:

```
class Synset {  
    static Hashtable<Integer,Synset> synset_access;  
    static Hashtable<String,Vector<Synset>> term_access;  
}
```

Some Prolog can do the same, by a indexing directive, it is
possible to instruct the Prolog system to index on multiple
arguments for a predicate.

Putting up a web service shouldn't be that difficult, either
in Java or Prolog. Many Prologs systems easily allow embedding
Prolog programs in web servers, and Java champions servlets.

A list of Prologs that support web servers can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Prolog_implementations#Operating_system_and_Web-related_features

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for this info, very very helpful. Quick question, I'm still not 100% sure on this, but if possible, what would be the best way to link a word like 'discouraged' to 'beat down' programatically?

Comment: Depends on the "link" and the programming language. In WordNet there are two kinds of "links", semantic and lexical. Via Prolog, for a semantic link, you would assert a fact link(synset_id1, synset_id2). For a lexical link you would assert a fact link(synset_id1, word_num1, synset_id2, word_num2). In Java you would use your appropriate datastructure/service. Or you put the two words into the same synset, or create a new synset where they are together in it. The later applies in case your "link" should represent same sense.

Answer (score 3):

These are two different problems.

1) Wordnet and python. Use NLTK, it has a nice [interface to wordnet](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html). You could write something on your own, but honestly why make life difficult? Lingpipe probably also has something built in but NLTK is much easier to use. I think nltk just downloads an ntlk database, but I'm pretty sure there are apis to talk to wordnet.

2) To get bigrams in nltk [follow this tutorial](http://jaganadhg.freeflux.net/blog/archive/2009/07/15/finding-bigrams-with-nltk.html). In general you tokenize text and then just iterate over the sentence getting all the n-grams for each word by looking forward and backward.

Comment: Thanks for the links. From my testings with WordNet certain phrases such as "beat down" cant be identified, is this correct?

Comment: If you use wordnet online you can see some synonyms: http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?c=8&sub=Change&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&i=-1&h=000&s=beat+down

Comment: maybe the online version is a newer db of words?

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to NLTK, you can use [one](http://wordnet.rkbexplorer.com/sparql/) of available WordNet SPARQL endpoints to retrieve such information. Query example:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wordnet: <http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/schema/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?label {
  ?input_word a wordnet:WordSense;
     rdfs:label ?input_label.
  FILTER (?input_label = 'run')
  ?synset wordnet:containsWordSense ?input_word.
  ?synset wordnet:containsWordSense ?synonym.
  ?synonym rdfs:label ?label.
} LIMIT 100
```

In Java universe, [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net) and [Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org) frameworks can be used.

Comment: if I replace 'run' with 'bicycle', as results I get bicycle, bike, cycle, but also wheel and pedal <-- why these last 2?